# How do I know that the drivers are installed and working properly on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I am a new user of Ubuntu. I switched from Windows to Ubuntu 12.04.

How can I know that all the drivers in Ubuntu on my machine are successfully installed and working properly?

I plan to install Ubuntu and remove Windows as soon as I'm able to determine this.

Comment: why not check all the functionalists. Like  networking is working or not, any GPU problem, test webcam, test SD card slot if any. If everything is working then you are good to go. :)

Answer (score 3):

Install `HardInfo` from Ubuntu Software Center (Applications –> Ubuntu Software Center).

After installing, go to Applications –> System Tools –> System Profiler and Benchmark.

You can view a summary of your system hardware information as depicted in screenshot below.

[image: summary of the system hardware information]

Extracted from [here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/11/check-hardware-information-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/).